# Are there HDDs which tolerate high ambient temperatures?

Tags: hard-drive, physical-environment

For certain reasons I won't go into, I have this small server machine which tends to overheat. I don't have exact temperature measurements, but let's say something like...

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   037   028   045    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 63
```

Now, I'm probably going to solve the matter differently (move the machine elsewhere, reduce the number of HDDs etc.) - but I was wondering: Can you get Magentic (non-solid-state) HDDs whose acceptable ambient operating temperatures range up to 60 or 70 degree Celsius? If so, can you get them for a bearable price, say, up to twice the price of consumer HDDs?

(I'm not asking for a recommendation of individual products or manufacturers.)

Comment: Since there's quite a niche market for rugged industrial systems with some quoting supported environmental operating temperatures up to 70℃ there must be. Did you try to search on *"industrial hard disk"*

Comment: The "certain reasons" you won't go into are probably very important, and you almost certainly should go into them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I am going into them, but I don't have anything to ask about them.

Answer (score 1):

Most systems I've seen with this requirement in the past few years use [industrial SSDs](https://serverfault.com/questions/576472/reliability-of-ssd-vs-hdd-over-large-temperature-variations/576480#576480). But I do have machinery that leverage [ruggedized and industrial hard disks](http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/automotive-and-industrial-drives) as well. The main difference over regular drives being an expanded operating temperature range.

But in order for this not to be an [*XY Problem*](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-the-xy-problem-and-why-is-it-bad--cms-21023) question, can you give the context of why the server you have is in such an environment?

Comment: It's in a small space which is poorly ventilated.